# How to create a theme in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am pretty newbie with WordPress and what I want to know is when creating a theme how to create the stylesheet file ? I mean WP has probably some classes that uses by default like post_class(). So should I only redefine some particular classes and ids from the default stylesheet that comes with the WP installation in my own stylesheet ? Also,are template files usually modified?
 I hope I wasn't to confusing.

Any other suggestions are appreciated .

Thanks !

Comment: You want to create a completely own template right?

Comment: I don't want right now to create a theme . I'm asking how is usually done . Supposing I want to create my own template what do I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

- To start building your theme, first create a sub-folder in the wp-content/themes directory in your WordPress folder.You start creating the theme, you should decide how the layout of your website will look like.
- See [Theme_Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)  for more information.
- When building your own theme, you can use our [Free WordPress themes](http://www.magikcommerce.com/magikshop-wordpress-theme/) for reference.